# Memory Allocation of Multicast delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I was reading about multicast delegate and thought of memory allocation stopped me.
Can someone explaing how memory allocation of multicast delegate is done.(I have intentionally not added any events to make it easier for me to understand)
In this program:

```
using System;

delegate int MyDelegate(int a,int b);
namespace DelegateAppl
{
    class DelegateTest
    {

        public static int AddNum(int p,int q)
        {
          int  add = p + q;
          return add;
        }

        public static int MultNum(int p, int q)
        {
            int mul = p * q;
            return mul;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDelegate myDel = new MyDelegate(AddNum);
            myDel += new MyDelegate(MultNum);


            int result = myDel(2, 5);
           Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", result);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How Mydelegate will be allocated.Will it have size of addNum or MultNum or addition of both size?

**MyThoughts**-The complier will allocate some memory(i have no idea how much) to Mydelegate and will store this in cache.It will then allocates memory as per method(ADD) and then removes and then again allocates memory as per Multiply method when called via delegates.
Am i right in understanding?

Comment: If you have enough delegates for their total memory to make up a non-zero percentage of your application you're doing something very very wrong.  You shouldn't *care* how much memory it takes for a delegate; it'll all round to zero.

Comment: Thanks Sir,I just wanted to know how memory of multicast delegates work.i have no intention to change or do anything fishy.Just for knowledge,what happens in case of multicast delegates as we can have a delegate that refres to two methods,one which print string and other do something with int.

Comment: Why downvote.I searched a lot before posting but could get any answer so posted.Will frame better question next time.Appologies if it sbelow level

Comment: @Servy: The question is not unreasonable.  There are some situations where the simplest implementation of an algorithm would result in multi-subscriber events getting attached and detached frequently.  Using `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove` will likely be fine for events which seldom have more than a handful of subscribers, and unsuitable for events with tens of thousands.  Where to draw the line, however, may be affected by how multicast delegates are stored, and whether all .NET versions use the same approach.  It would not be hard to imagine a scenario...

Comment: ...where manipulating 500-subscriber events in one version of .NET might generate 100 times as much GC churn as in another.  I don't think .NET event handling has ever changed in such fashion, but it's not hard to imagine it doing so.

Comment: @supercat But it doesn't appear that the OP is in a situation where he has tens of thousands of subscribers for an event, nor is he having performance problems as a result of the current implementation of delegates.  A question in which someone described a situation that they're in that involves that many delegates and explains the problems it's causing would potentially have value.  I also wouldn't consider a program that's subscribing tens of thousands of handlers for an event to be a particularly realistic situation to be in.

Comment: Thanks for you opinions,but as beginner frankly,most of your talk went above me.I asked the question out of curosity that in pgm shown above,no events and no subscriber,just delegates .Will it take any memory and if yes,is there any fix  criteria

Comment: @eric lippert,@ JonSkeet -Sir,I am great admirer of all intelligent ppl out here,especially you two .CAn you please help me in nderstanding memory mangement of multicast delegates especifically to above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate gets compiled to a private sealed class (of the containing class), which is hidden from you - it is generated during compile time. Every time you initialize a delegate, like `MyDelegate myDel = new MyDelegate(AddNum);`, you are actually initializing an instance of that hidden class. That class also contains a field called `_invocationList`, of type System.Object, which is used to reference to another delegate, and is assigned via `Delegate.Combine(Delegate that, Delegate other)`, which is what really happens when you write `myDel += new MyDelegate(MultNum);`. From that you can figure out how memory is allocated - it's an instantiation of regular objects.

Comment: Thanks Sir, then in case of multicast declaration with anonymous method,the size of delegates object will combine the size of all method it refers.Say if delegate d has refrence to 5 methods(a,b,c,d,e), then 5 refrence will get added in _invocationList,which all became garbage as we have not saved them for future(they are just anonymous).Am I right in understanding? and is the size of refrence in  _invocationList fixed?

Comment: `_invocationList` is like the `Next` field of a linked list, pointing to the next delegate in the chain. Anonymous method gets compiled to private method anyway, so they're not a special case. When you are chaining 5 delegates, you merely creates a linked list of 5 nodes.

Comment: Thanks,any size information if you could provide on size of this Next field?Is it equal to size of method it points or some fixed value?

Comment: I wrote in the answer - it's a System.Object type, so the size is of a reference.

Comment: ah..ok.Thanks Sir.Could get that.Appologies.

Comment: @user5110999 If you are interested in such topics, I would recommend "CLR cia C#" by Jeffery Richter, and "Under the Hood of .NET Memory Management" by   Chris Farrell and Nick Harrison

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and ordered also :)